# Getting an error related to apt-key deprecation

Tags: apt, updates, repository, gnupg, keyrings

When I tried to run `sudo apt update` I got the following errors related to NO_PUBKEY 67170598AF249743.

```
Err:8 https://packages.osrfoundation.org/gazebo/ubuntu-stable jammy InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 67170598AF249743
```

I used this:

```
apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 67170598AF249743
```

but then the following command returned this message:

```
Warning: apt-key is deprecated. Manage keyring files in trusted.gpg.d instead (see apt-key(8)).
Executing: /tmp/apt-key-gpghome.N9JbawXvIX/gpg.1.sh --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 67170598AF249743
gpg: key 67170598AF249743: "OSRF Repository (OSRF Repository GPG key) <osrfbuild@osrfoundation.org>" not changed
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:              unchanged: 1
W: The key(s) in the keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/osrf-key.gpg are ignored as the file has an unsupported filetype.
```

How do I go about this? Also the warning says that the osrf-key.gpg file is an unsupported file type. What does this mean. and how do I get that file working?